# I want to add another field to be displayed in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

After I press enter I would like positions as well as the player names to be displayed. I feel like i am close but its not quite clicking.

```
Select
    Players.fname AS first_name,
    Players.lname AS last_name,
    Players.Player_id
    positions.positions_id
From
    Players, positions
JOIN player_position
ON Players.Player_id=player_position.Player_id
JOIN positions ON player_position.positions_id=positions.positions_id
WHERE player_position.WAR> 5
GROUP BY last_name
\G`
```

Comment: don't mix join styles. that just makes for an ugly/unmaintainable query.

Comment: Needs a comma after `Players.Player_id` on your select.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you were not really that "close" to getting it right. Quite a number of points need fixing. Let's give it a try:

```
SELECT
  pl.fname AS first_name,
  pl.lname AS last_name,
  pl.Player_id,
  po.positions_id
FROM Players pl 
INNER JOIN player_position pp
ON pp.position_id=pl.Player_id
INNER JOIN positions po
ON po.positions_id=pp.positions_id
WHERE pp.WAR> 5
ORDER BY last_name
```

Not really knowing much about your data and their internal structure I can only guess, so very likely this is not exactly what you want but at least it should be valid SQL and maybe a starting point.

I replaced your `GROUP BY` by `ORDER BY` assuming that you actually want to see each player separately and not all players with the same last name lumped together into a single line. Your column list would not have been admissible for the `GROUP BY` clause either.

Another point not clear to me is the purpose of your apparent two positioning tables `player_position` and `positions`. They are both joined to an individual player id. Are there really two tables or did you want to do something different there?